# How to use protorpc messages and datastore models correctly in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, protorpc

I'm finding myself writing datastore models, and then repeating the exact same set of attributes for their respective messages. Is there any smart way to convert between datastore entities and protorpc messages? A kind of built in to_message method, or do I have to do it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this : http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/
This library permit to use models directly in endpoints request. I advice you to read the library documentation.

GitHub repository : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore

Comment: Pay attention,  in case you want to run your app engine instance for your own site with your own domain, Google Cloud Endpoint doesn't support custom domain. You will must use yourid.appspot.com domain

Comment: Yes we must specify the real URL API.